# Pythonic way to pass external input to singleton-like module/class

Tags: python, module, arguments, singleton, parameter-passing

I am trying to adapt a singleton example from *Real Python*, and I have simplified the code for clarity.

```
# employees.py


class _EmployeeDatabase:
    def __init__(self):
        self._employees = {
            1: {
                'name': 'Mary Poppins',
                'role': 'manager'
            },
            2: {
                'name': 'John Smith',
                'role': 'secretary'
            },
            3: {
                'name': 'Kevin Bacon',
                'role': 'sales'
            },
            4: {
                'name': 'Jane Doe',
                'role': 'factory'
            },
            5: {
                'name': 'Robin Williams',
                'role': 'secretary'
            }
        }

    def employees(self):
        return [Employee(id_) for id_ in sorted(self._employees)]

    def get_employee_info(self, employee_id):
        info = self._employees.get(employee_id)
        if not info:
            raise ValueError('invalid employee_id')
        return info


class Employee:
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id
        info = employee_database.get_employee_info(self.id)
        self.name = info.get('name')
        self._role = get_role(info.get('role'))



employee_database = _EmployeeDatabase()
```

**What I want** is to replace the content of `self._employees` with a dictionary I generated from user input (called `dict_employees` if you will).

**What would be the pythonic way to pass `dict_employees` to `class _EmployeeDatabase`?**

What seem to be preventing me from passing the dictionary to the class are that

1. If `employee_database = _EmployeeDatabase(dict_employees)` takes place outside the module `employees.py`, `class Employee` loses access to `employee_database`.
2. On the other hand, I do not want to naively import the module where `dict_employees` is generated for various reasons*.

Sorry in case this is a duplicate question but I am not familiar with Python enough to tell.

===========================

* You probably do not need to know but one reason is that `dict_employees` has already been generated before my program needs the `employees.py` module. Another reason is that my program is running multiprocessing and importing `dict_employees` will result in it being generated multiple times which is wasteful.

Comment: What's wrong with adding a dict argument to `_EmployeeDatabase.__init__`?

Comment: As explained in my question, I will need this statement: ```employee_database = _EmployeeDatabase(dict_employees)```. But where would I put this statement? If it is outside the module ```employees.py```, ```class Employee``` loses access to ```employee_database```; if it is left where it currently is, I seem to have to import ```dict_employees``` from where it is born which I am trying to avoid for reasons explained at the end of my question.

Comment: I guess I want to modify the module in a way such that ```employee_database = _EmployeeDatabase(dict_employees)``` can be stated outside the module, if this is the right direction of thinking...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think one of your issues is that the values for an Employee instance get set upon init rather than at runtime. If you'd like Employee instances to update their data when employee_database is changed, it seems to me that you have two options:

- implement an `update()` routine in the Employee class which must be called on each instance when `employee_database` is updated
- instead of setting values in `Employee.__init__()`, use getter routines which look the information up every time.

I'm guessing the second method makes the most sense for your application.

Once that's fixed up, you can technically do the (horrible, horrible)

```
employees.employee_database._employees = dict_employees
```

where `dict_employees` is your input. However, a more Pythonic way would be to create a routine that does this from inside the _EmployeeDatabase class:

```
    def set_employee_database(self, newdict):
       self._employee_database = newdict
```

and then run:

```
employee.employee_database.set_employee_database(newdict)
```

from outside the employee module.